# Method selector with suds

Tags: python, suds

I'm using the suds library  with python 2.7.

My question is how can I invoke a method by name. I know that for example if we want to run the method `X` of a web service we use

```
result = client.service.X("a","b",...)
```

But I want to run methods from many web services so I don't know the list of methods in every web service.
I read in the documentation of suds that there is a class named `MethodSelector` but I don't know how to use it.

---

Does anyone know how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use [`operator.method_caller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller). E.g.:

```
import operator as op

f = op.methodcaller('X','a','b')
f(client.service)
```